# How to get recently updated MySQL field in a row using PHP (NOT ROW)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `TESTING`, with fields e.g.

> id,city,county,first_name,last_name,update_time etc.

I would to get only the field that was recently updated using PHP.

E.g. If last_name was the recently updated field, I would like to display last_name (not the row).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Do you log each update event? Do you already know what is the recently updated field?

Comment: How do you track which field was most recently updated?

Comment: I don't have any log for the update. I know how to get the row that has been updated but I only want to display the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to log the change in another table. Like `changes` with the attributes: `id`, `table`, `attribute`, `old_value`, `new_value`, `datetime`. Then, whenever something changes you add e.g.

id, TESTING, last_name, Doe, DoKnow, 2015-03-06 12:34:56

Then you can use this table to show the latest changes. But in the long run and for big databases you end up with a huge `changes`table. ;)